# How to compare string content of two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, compare

I have two vectors and want to compare their contents (strings) but this does not work:

```
    vector<string>inwords = getInWords();
    vector<string>killwords = getKillWords();


    vector<string>::iterator it;
    vector<string>::iterator ut;

    for(it = inwords.begin(); it < inwords.end(); it++){
     for (ut = killwords.begin(); ut < killwords.end(); ut++) {
      if (*ut == *it){
       cout << "match" << endl;
      }
     }
    }
```

I also tried the compare function:

```
    if (killwords[u].compare(inwords[i]) == 0)
```

My guess is that I need to overload the == operator, but I am not sure how to do that. Would be nice if you could help me out, as my google searches have not really gotten me anywhere. Cheers!

Comment: What do you want to check? If the vectors have the same strings in the same order? The same strings in a different order? If they have at least one string in common? Something else?

Comment: For what I can tell by the code, if there are strings in each that are present in the other?

Comment: @Michael: Since OP says the code doesn't work, looking at it won't reveal what he intended to do.

Comment: I want to check if a word in the inwords vector is also in the killwords vector. Michaels suggestion is correct.

Comment: @sytycs, which word? You want to see if *any* of the words in the first vector is present in the other? Your code seems to be correct, check the input or be more specific about the problems you have.

Comment: Did you check that `inwords` and `killwords` really contain whatever you think they contain? Maybe the error is in `getInWords` or `getKillWords`.

Comment: -1 for a rather unclear question and failing to provide the information in the question after been asked for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying with your code you might want to use `std::find_first_of`. If you're trying to compare ranges for (un)equality you may want to look at `std::mismatch` or `std::equal`.

For anything else you want to achieve you better be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should print "match" on the intersected strings between the two vectors, it should work fine for the intersection, you may need to check the string value itself, it may contain spaces or so